# Windows 10 machine hangs for no apparent reason

Tags: windows, windows-10

Greetings fellow humans.

I am experiencing a weird issue with a Windows 10 Pro 64 (20H2) machine that stops responding for no apparent reason.
What makes troubleshooting hard is that the PC doesn't have a GPU, I use it exclusively via RDP.
The PC works fine all day, but when I come back in the morning the RDP session is disconnected and can't reconnect with a "Can't be found" error.
I have verified that it is not responding to PING as well.

I have set sleep / hibernate / screen saver to OFF and the power plan is set to 'high performance'.
I see nothing in the windows logs that hints something went wrong.
I even tried installing a utility called 'Caffeine' that tricks the PC to think it's being used all the time, but it still stops responding.

Since it has no monitor or keyboard / mouse (it's in my basement), I am lost as to how to troubleshoot it.
The only way to get it back up is to go down to the basement and physically reset it.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Stay safe!

Comment: I suggest hooking up a monitor, keyboard, and mouse temporarily in order to see what is happening when this behavior.  Depending on what's actually happening it might be obvious, but based on the information you provided, it will difficult for us to troubleshoot the behavior

Comment: I agree with the above. Also (as part of normal maintenance) use the manufacturer's Driver Update app to update all drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ramhound and John. All drivers are up to date, and I was trying to avoid installing a GPU on it and was hoping for an easier way to at least troubleshoot what is going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I bit the bullet, purchased a $30 NVIDIA GEFORCE 710 GPU, and installed it, anticipating a revelation.

Since then, the PC hasn't hanged even once...

Seems like the quantum "[Observer Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics))" in action...

### BE SAFE!